# PHP curl doesn't work, but terminal curl does

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a PUT request to an API.  The request is successful if I do the following in Terminal:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer abc123" -X PUT -d "story[title]=Testing" "http://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/stories/1.json"
```

This curl works just fine but when I try to do it using PHP with the following code it's not working:

```
$curlOptions = array
        (
          CURLOPT_URL            => "https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/stories/1.json",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: Bearer abc123'),
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "story[title]=Testing"
        );

        $curlHandle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, $curlOptions);

        $content = curl_exec($curlHandle);

        if ($content === false) {
            print_r(curl_error($curlHandle));
        }

        print_r($content);
```

What I get printed when I go to the page is an error SSL Connect Error.  I've searched around and tried multiple curl options:

```
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => "rsa_rc4_128_sha",
```

Neither remedy the problem.  Why would it work in Terminal but not in PHP if the options are the same?  What's missing from the PHP that's causing the error?  Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Based on Mikel's answer I changed the PHP url to http.  This did not show an error but it also wasn't successful.  So I did a curl_getinfo and go the following:

```
Array ( [url] => https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/stories/1.json [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 301 [header_size] => 237 [request_size] => 435 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 1 [total_time] => 0.216551 [namelookup_time] => 4.1E-5 [connect_time] => 0.043997 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 0 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0.21663 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_ip] => 55.555.555.555 [redirect_url] => )
```

So I added `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,` to the curl options in the PHP code.  After trying that I still get the error SSL Connect Error

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the API you're trying to connect to does not allow secured connections. Your terminal example is connecting to just http://, while your php code is trying to connect to https://. Try changing the URL of the API in your PHP to just http://.

EDIT: Also, looks like you're new to SO! Welcome! Please remember to cast votes as you go ;D

Comment: Interesting.  I've tried http in the PHP and it still didn't work earlier.  I'll try again to see results.  I'll post a reply in a moment.  Thanks for the warm welcome!

Comment: I have added an update to the post based on your suggestions.